# How to programmatically set username and password on Geoserver at intall time

Tags: bash, geoserver

I am writing a bash script to install Geoserver by following the steps outlined here [Install Instructions](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/linux/debian.html#installation) .  I am trying to use CURL to post a custom data store config file.  But I am having an authentication error.

```
    * upload completely sent off: 42out of 42 bytes
    < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
    < Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    < Set-Cookie: SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE=""; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/geoserver
    * Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
    < WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="GeoServer Realm"
    < Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
    < Content-Length: 1299
    < Date: Thu, 31 Jan 2013 05:16:17 GMT
```

I belive it is becuase I haven't set the username and password for Geoserver.  The only way I can seem to find is to do it via the web admin interface.  I would like to set it via my bash script.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Bash script section here

```
    echo 'Downdloading geoserver'
    wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/geoserver/GeoServer/2.2.4/geoserver-2.2.4-war.zip

    unzip geoserver-2.2.4-war.zip
    sudo cp geoserver.war /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/

    sleep 120

    echo 'setting up geoserver'

    curl -u $U_NAME:$PASSWORD -v -XPOST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' \
       -d '<workspace><name>catami</name></workspace>' \
       http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces ;

    curl -u $U_NAME:$PASSWORD -XPOST -T datastore-config.xml -H 'Content-type: text/xml' \
      http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/catami/datastores ;

    curl -u $U_NAME:$PASSWORD -XPOST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' \
      -d '<featureType><name>Force_image</name></featureType>' \
      http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/catami/datastores/CatamiImagePoints/featuretypes ;

    curl -u $U_NAME:$PASSWORD -XPOST -H 'Content-type: application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml' \
      -d @catami-colour-by-depth.sld http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/styles ;

    curl -u $U_NAME:$PASSWORD -XPUT -H 'Content-type: text/xml' \
      -d '<layer><defaultStyle><name>catami-colour-by-depth</name></defaultStyle><enabled>true</enabled></layer>' \
      http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/catami:Force_image
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can edit the username and password inside the GeoServer Data Directory. You can read more about it [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/gettingstarted/web-admin-quickstart/index.html).

And after you found what file to change what it, then you just need to `sed` that data to your liking.